# Get Card Type from Stripe STPPaymentCardTextField

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments, credit-card

I'm using the `STPPaymentCardTextField` to collect card information from the user.

I can use the delegate method of the `STPPaymentCardTextFieldDelegate` to get information like the `'cardNumber`, `expirationMonth` etc:

```
func paymentCardTextFieldDidChange(_ textField: STPPaymentCardTextField) {
   print("NUMBER", textField.cardNumber)
   print("EXP MONTH", textField.expirationMonth)
   print("EXP YEAR", textField.expirationYear)
   print("CVC", textField.cvc)   
}
```

However, this textField seems to also display the card type, based on the info the user types in: [image]

How can I programmatically access this card type? I use this in another `UIView` to generate a preview of the card, set its background color and logo based on the card type etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the brand image directly: https://stripe.dev/stripe-ios/docs/Classes/STPPaymentCardTextField.html#/c:objc(cs)STPPaymentCardTextField(py)brandImage

In your case it'll be `textField.brandImage`.

Answer (score 0):

```
// number = credit card number

let card = CreditCardValidator()
let imageName = card.type(from: number)
        
print(imageName!.name)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes

Answer (score 0):

You can use STPCardValidator , [Stripe Docs for Card Validator](https://stripe.dev/stripe-ios/docs/Classes/STPCardValidator.html#/c:@M@Stripe@objc(cs)STPCardValidator(cm)brandForNumber:).

if you want to print the type in above function , here is the code

```
func paymentCardTextFieldDidChange(_ textField: STPPaymentCardTextField) {
   print("NUMBER", textField.cardNumber)
   print("EXP MONTH", textField.expirationMonth)
   print("EXP YEAR", textField.expirationYear)
   print("CVC", textField.cvc)   
   print("Brand Type", STPCardValidator.brand(forNumber: textField.cardNumber))
}
```

Comment: https://stripe.dev/stripe-android/stripe/com.stripe.android/-card-utils/index.html if you want to look for android as well. where you can use getPossibleCardBrand